# android firebase reg id recived but notification not show in phone display

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I will try to show personal single notification on my phone tray, but I can't rich, so help.

I am having an issue with FireBase Cloud Messaging in which I get the Token from the device and send the notification test through the Google Firebase notification console, however, the notification is never logged nor pushed to the android virtual device. The documentation for FCM is almost exactly the code that I have below and little else in the way of what else you would have to do to get push notifications working with firebase. I have gone through all of the setup information (build.gradle additions, Installing google play services, etc...) as specified in the documentation, but still do not have messages generating. What is wrong with the code that I am not receiving my push notifications to the logcat or the device? Please let me know any further information that would be helpful. Thanks.

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) 
              {
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };

    displayFirebaseRegId();
}

    private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
    else
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
 }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

    NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

And I will add lib of fire base messaging is:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to subscribe inside the BroadcastReceiver you can just do it inside the `onTokenRefresh` method in the FirebaseInstanceIdService

You don't need to get the push notification in the BroadcastReceiver, you have to do it inside the `onMessageReceive` in the FirebaseMessagingService

FCM is extremely unreliable with emulators, simply use a real device, I have struggled with this and in some cases I even get the notification days later when opening the emulator for other projects, test this with real phones